# Add active class to current menu with extension method or jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, comparative-review, mvc

In the layout, I have a menu that contains some `ul` and `li`.
I have three levels`. This code is a bit of a sample:

```
<li class="@(IsAny(MVC.Admin.Setting.Name) ? "active" : "")">
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-paperclip"></i> <span class="nav-label">reports</span><span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
    <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
        <li class="@(IsAny("Failure","FailureCostByLocation") ? "active" : "")">
            <a href="#">text <span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
            <ul class="nav nav-third-level">
                <li class="@(Is("ReportCostByData") ? "active" : "")"><a href="@Url.Action(MVC.Admin.Failure.ReportCostByData())">text</a></li>
                <li class="@(Is("FailureCostByLocation") ? "active" : "")"><a href="@Url.Action(MVC.Admin.Failure.FailureCostByLocation())"> text</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

To select the current menu item, I use this code:

```
 public bool IsAny(params string[] controllers)
    {
        return controllers.Any(c => Is(c));
    }

    public bool Is(string controller, string action = null)
    {
        if (ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"].ToString().ToLower() == controller.ToLower()
            && (action == null ||
             ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Action"].ToString().ToLower() == action.ToLower()))
            return true;
        return false;
    }
```

If I use jQuery, is it better than this one on page load speed?  Or is there a way to do this in faster way?

The jQuery code looks like this:

```
(function(){
    var current = 'current location';
    $('#nav li a').each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        // if the current path is like this link, make it active
        if($this.attr('href').indexOf(current) !== -1){
            $this.addClass('active');
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: This is an interesting quesiton but in its current form off-topic because there is no jquery implementation yet and you are asking about this part which is not yet written. If you added both solutions (working) then it could be a comparative-review.

Comment: @t3chb0t OP isn't asking for a review of a jQuery implementation, but is asking a broader question of 'would using jQuery (doing this client side) be better?'.

Comment: Ok I'll updated and add jquery script.  but befor add jquery code Iant to know is jquery better than this code ?

Comment: @t3chb0t updated

Answer (score 3):

Regardless of whether you use jQuery or C# to handle the operation it won't have a dramatic effect on page load speed, the only difference will be latency perceived by the user. Because of the manner in which JavaScript operates, you will *likely* find that the button does not appear as 'active' when the user first loads the page for 0.25 to 0.5s, which may not  be a big deal to *you*, but a user would potentially see that flicker and wonder what they did.

The only changes I would make for you is to rewrite your method just a little to read a bit cleaner:

> ```
> public bool Is(string controller, string action = null)
> {
>     if (ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"].ToString().ToLower() == controller.ToLower()
>         && (action == null ||
>          ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Action"].ToString().ToLower() == action.ToLower()))
>         return true;
>     return false;
> }
> ```

To something like the following:

```
public bool Is(string controller, string action = null) 
{
    var routeData = ViewContext.RouteData;
    var actController = routeData.Values["Controller"].ToString();
    var actAction = routeData.Values["Action"].ToString();

    return actController.ToLower() == controller.ToLower() && (action == null || actAction.ToLower() == action.ToLower());
}
```

Same number of LoC, but it's a little more clear what's happening.

As far as performance, I don't see any obvious bottlenecks. I think the biggest bottleneck you'll end up having is in the LINQ (this is all speculation, but we're talking microseconds, not even nanoseconds). You shouldn't be concerned of your performance until *there's a measurable performance issue.*

Comment: if I use JqueryIt just run once , but when I use extension methods It runs for each links , for example I have more than 50 links In my page and for each request it runs 50 times